# How to call Jquery.Event with params via Trigger so it calls a function too?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$("#test").trigger(jQuery.Event("contextmenu", { data: e.data, pageX: e.pageX, pageY: e.pageY, rowState: state }));
```

The actual event is defined as:

```
$.menu({
    selector: '#test',
        items: {
            doactiveswitch: {name: "Make - " + rowState, callback: alert_click},
        }, 
});
```

Everything above works, except for the "+state" part. How can I change this so that the "rowState" is recognized inside the menu?

I've tried:

```
this.rowState
rowState
data.rowState
e.rowState
```

Any other suggestion on how to reference it?

Comment: what exactly is `$.menu`?

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle and more code

Comment: Not enough to go on, please provide more of your code... a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net) would suffice.

Comment: Provide the more details in which able to look into the issue properly.

Answer (score 1):

You really should paste more code of Yours to let people see what is going on there. 
From what I see I suggest You to try e.data.rowState. 
;)
You can also use console.log() in Chrome to see what is behind the "this" or "e" variables in this scope. Chrome displays such objects nice and clean.